# bash how to allow interactive session when runing through a pipe

Tags: bash

I'm creating a script that I want people to run with

```
 curl -sSL install.domain.com | bash
```

As RVM, oh-my-zsh and many others does,

However, I'm having issues because my script is interactive (it uses `read` and `select`, and the user is not being prompted, the script just skip those steps as is being executed with a `|`.

I've tried adding `{}` to my whole code.

I was thinking in ask the script to download himself again and put in tmp folder, and execute from there, not sure if that will work.

Comment: Executing code streamed directly from a remote site is a security risk, as the code is executed before the user can verify that they are receiving the script they (and you) expect they will receive.

Answer (score 1):

You can  explicitly tell `read` to read from the terminal using

```
read var < /dev/tty
```

Comment: And that makes `yes | script` impossible (hard)... Maybe ask users to use process substitution instead, which frees up stdin for interactive use?

Comment: @4ae1e1 I see the issue. Probably the simplest would be to ask users to download the script first and then execute it. Oh no, this would be too simple! :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found is ask user to run it like:

```
bash <( curl -sSL install.domain.com )
```

This way script is passed as an argument and standard input remains untouched.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-problem, as users should not be executing code directly from the stream. The user *should* be downloading the code to a file first, then verifying that the script they receive has, for example, an MD5 hash that matches the hash you provide on your website. Only after confirming that the script they receive is the script you sent should they execute it.

```
$ curl -sSL install.domain.com > installer.sh
$ md5sum installer.bash  # Does the output match the hash posted on install.domain.com?
$ bash installer.bash
```